# Creating a special block matrix

Tags: matrices, block

I'm trying to create an special block matrix with the following structure:

[image]

Would you please guide me on how to design it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\|Ar_0\|}{\|r_0\|} & \multirow{2}{*}{$\widetilde G_{m-1}$} \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and considerations.